# invalid syntax error when using for loop on a zip object

Tags: python, for-loop, zip, syntax-error

I'm learning how to optimize for loops in python 3.7, and I keep getting an "invalid syntax error". I've already checked for missing parenthesis. Here's the code:

```
    best = probabilities[0]
    best = (probabilities[i] for i in range(1, len(probabilities)) if probabilities[i] > best)
    print(best)
    prob, im = (prob, im for prob, im in zip(probabilities, image_names) if prob == best)

    return (prob, im)
```

gives me the error

```
  File "path", line 27
    prob, im = (prob, im for prob, im in zip(probabilities, image_names) if prob == best)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what went wrong, as the following code I used in another exercise uses pretty much the same syntax:

```
im = [im for im, prob in zip(image_names, probabilities) if prob >= threshold]
    return (im)
```

Edit:
I've also tried

```
return (prob, im for prob, im in zip(probabilities, image_names) if prob == best)
```

and it says that the variable type is a Generator[tuple[float, str], Any, None] but I'm not sure what it means.

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Once you fix the syntax error, this still makes no sense. The generator creates a tuple of tuples of the form `((prob, im), (prob, im), (prob, im), ...)` and then you're assigning this to two variables.

Comment: FYI, the first loop can be simplified to just `best = max(probabiliites)`

Comment: @Barmar I wanted to put the values of the tuple inside the variables prob and im if the value of `prob` is equal to `best`.

Comment: Also I didn't know that there was a max function, so thanks for the information

Comment: You want to get separate tuples of all the `prob` and `im` values that are selected in the generator?

Comment: no, just the tuple with the maximum probability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples need to be explicitly wrapped in `()` when being produced by a comprehension/generator expression:

```
((prob, im) for prob, im in zip(probabilities, image_names) if prob == best)
```

Comment: Do you mean `prob, im = ((prob, im) for prob, im in zip(probabilities, image_names) if prob == best)`? I tried it but I got `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: @RJ9 That's the point I was making in my comment above. You're trying to assign two variables, but the generator produces a different number of tuples. You seem to be expecting it to pivot the data for you.

Comment: @RJ9 That's an unrelated error that's showing now that the syntax error is fixed.

Comment: Add `[0]` to the end of the generator to get the first element of the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this much more complicated than necessary.

Just set both variables during the same loop

```
best = probabilities[0]
best_image = image_names[0]
for index, prob in enumerate(probabilities):
    if prob > best:
        best = prob
        best_image = image_names[index];
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I would normally do but the goal is to get the code to be as fast as possible

Comment: I believe this is as fast as possible.

Comment: it's definitively a lot faster than the one I wrote after reading the answers `return (tuple( (prob, im) for prob, im in zip(probabilities, image_names) if prob == best)[0])`, but it's still ~30% slower than the code that I'm supposed to optimize.

Comment: `best_name, best_proba = image_names[0], probabilities[0]

    for i in range(1, n):

        if best_proba < probabilities[i]:

            best_proba, best_name = probabilities[i], image_names[i]


    return best_proba, best_name`

Comment: That's almost identical to my code, the only difference is the use of `best_name` instead of `best_index`. I find it difficult to believe there's a 30% difference.

Comment: How big are the lists?

Comment: from what I understood, it's a list of 10 000 elements and the function is executed 1000 times

Comment: I thought I was optimizing by not assigning the image whenever `best` was updated, but I was fooling myself. Assigning `best_index` is no cheaper than assigning `best_name`.

Comment: Maybe the difference is that `range()` is faster than `enumerate()`.

Comment: I found some questions about the performance differences. Most of them are old and some use Python 2.x, so I'm not sure how applicable they are now. 30% difference still seems surprising.

Comment: I've removed the extra `best_index` variable, but I'm sticking with `enumerate()`.

Comment: I ran the code a couple more times and the difference seems to be about 25-30%. I'll ask the person who made this for the answer and see if he would mind me posting it here.